# Powershell Set-Location Auto truncate spaces error

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I want to write a batch file named `install.bat` that will run a Powershell script file `install.ps1` as Administrator. The content of the batch file `install.bat` as simple as below:

```
@echo off
PowerShell -NoExit -Command "Start-Process PowerShell -Verb RunAs '-NoExit -Command "Set-Location ''%cd%''; .\install.ps1"'"
```

In this batch script, I call a Powershell to run the `Start-Process` command. This `Start-Process` command would invoke another Powershell as Administrator. The second Powershell would run `Set-Location` command to set working directory to `%cd%` then invoke the `install.ps1` script. An error happens with the `Set-Location` command if i run the `install.bat` file from a folder with more than 1 consecutive space characters in its name, for example:

```
D:\New    folder
```

`install.bat` script will run normally with folder has 1 space character in its name, for example:

```
D:\New folder
```

but if a folder has more than 1 consecutive space character like:

```
D:\New   folder
```

then `Set-Location` will searching for folder:

```
D:\New folder
```

and will show this error incase `D:\New folder` does not exist:
[image]

Can anyone explain this error and give me a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that I looked with your script was the various control characters (single-quotes, double-quotes, etc.).  Nothing obvious stood out.

I looked for other examples, but double-spaces in path names is not necessarily a common occurrence.

So I poked around and did some tests in a Command Prompt box, created a comparable test directory, and checked to see what outputs I could get.

First I sent the Current Directory variable to a PowerShell command to echo the value:

```
C:\temp\test\test  123>powershell -Command "Write-Host %cd%"
```

The output had stripped one of the space characters from the path name as you had described (*double-quotes added for clarity*):

```
"C:\temp\test\test 123"
```

Then I tried it with the variable within single-quotes:

```
C:\temp\test\test  123>powershell -Command "Write-Host '%cd%'"
```

This output preserved the space characters of the path name correctly (*double-quotes added for clarity*):

```
"C:\temp\test\test  123"
```

Then I tried it with the variable within two pairs of single-quotes as you had used in your script:

```
C:\temp\test\test  123>powershell -Command "Write-Host ''%cd%''"
```

This output also stripped one of the space characters from the path name, and it also added a space character to the front of the returned value (*double-quotes added for clarity*):

```
" C:\temp\test\test 123"
```

So it seems that your script might get corrected by changing to one pair of single-quotes surrounding the Current Directory variable call instead of the two pairs of single-quotes.

I'm not sure if you had another purpose for using the two pairs of single-quotes, and I suppose that most processes might not care about the extra leading space on the value return.

I hope that this helps with your script.

Comment: Hello KJohnson_SoCal, thank you for your answer. 
The reason for 2 single qoutes in `''%cd%''` is to escape the single quote character so that Set-Location command will appear like this in the Powershell: `Set-Location 'D:\New   folder'`

Comment: Maybe you can capture value from '%cd%' into another variable and pass that into the other command.